# How can I post a form content that is not related to a model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have an assignment where I need to capture three values in a form, submit them, do a specific operation with the values based on some conditions that will lead me to an index of a database row, fetch a row from the database with the calculated index and then update the view.

The problem is that the form per se is not a model nor does create an instance/entity/row in a table. When I create the view I get an error from Razor that says that the expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation, I know that it's because the form is not related to any model (and thus I'm not adding the @model directive in the .cshtml file). I think I need to POST the content to a Controller and with the fetched value update the content (I did try using a submit button, but it redirected me to an empty page, I know that's how forms usually function, but that's not the behavior I need).

I tried adding the @model directive to the Index.cshtml file that contains the form, but since the model I'm attaching the Index does not contain the same attributes as the ones I'm using in the form, Razor throws errors. I tried creating a Model class for the form and it somehow works, I get the values and all (it redirects on submit, thats not what I want) but I don't believe it's the correct thing to do since the form itself is not for creating an entity in the Table.

This is the Model from which I will be getting the values from the database:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PrototipoExploratorio.Models
{
    public partial class Factores
    {
        public int FactorId { get; }
        public int ValorUno { get; }
        public int ValorDos { get; }
        public int ValorTres { get; }
    }
}
```

This is the form, currently its inside the folder Views/Factores (as the model above)

```html
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Factores</h2>
<form method="post" asp-controller="FactoresForm" asp-action="ObtenerFactor">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Estatura" class="control-label">Estatura en centímetros</label>
        <input asp-for="Estatura" name="estatura" type="number" id="estatura" placeholder="168, 190, 155...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Edad" class="control-label">Edad</label>
        <input asp-for="Edad" name="edad" type="text" id="number" placeholder="15, 24, 50...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Peso" class="control-label">Peso en kilogramos</label>
        <input asp-for="Peso" name="peso" type="number" id="peso" placeholder="80, 70.5, 55.40...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="EstadoCivil" class="control-label">Estado civil</label>
        <select id="EstadoCivil" asp-for="EstadoCivil" for="EstadoCivil" name="EstadoCivil">
            <option value="soltero">Soltero</option>
            <option value="casado">Casado</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <label class="control-label">Factor calculado: </label>
            <h6 id="FactorCalculado">{this is where I will update the value calculated from the values submitted here and the database row that I will fetch}</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button asp-controller="FactoresForm" asp-action="ObtenerFactor" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Obtener factor</button>
            <button asp-controller="FactoresForm" asp-action="LimpiarDatos" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Limpiar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the controller:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using PrototipoExploratorio.Models;

namespace PrototipoExploratorio.Controllers {
    public class FactoresForm : Controller {
        // GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index() {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        // I expect to reach this code on form submit
        // I know that right now this does not work given the explanation above
        public IActionResult ObtenerFactor() {
            Console.WriteLine("");
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

I expect to submit the form, do some business logic operations to get the index of the database row (which is mapped to the Factores model), get the value from the row and update the view.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that the form per se is not a model nor does create an instance/entity/row in a table

You misunderstood the role of View Model. A View Model is a **`POCO`** (Plain Old CLR Object) which is used to render the **view**. It can be any plain simple object. An entity is usually known as [Data Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/adding-model?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#add-a-data-model-class) that represents a row in datatable.

> I tried creating a Model class for the form and it somehow works, I get the values and all (it redirects on submit, thats not what I want) but I don't believe it's the correct thing to do since the form itself is not for creating an entity in the Table.

In fact, that's the correct way. Just remember:

1. the **`View Model`** is used to render the view. It has nothing to do with the Data Model.
2. The [**`DTO`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) is used to transfer the data. DTO doesn't have to share the same type of Data Model.
3. You can define your **custom** `DTO`/`View Model` as you need.

---

#### How to fix

1. In this scenario, you'll render the view and then post the data to controller. To avoid the confusing "model" naming, let's create a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) to hold the data.

   ```
   public class FactorDto
   {
       public int Estatura {get;set;}
       public int Edad {get;set;}
       public decimal Peso {get;set;}
       public string EstadoCivil {get;set;}
   }
   ```

   The name `FactorDto` doesn't matter at all. Feel free to change the name as you like.
2. To render the form view with this `DTO`, you can add a `@model` directive in your form view file:

   ```
   @model FactorDto
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
   }

   <h2>Factores</h2>
   ...
   ```
3. Finally, change your controller as below to receive the data sent from browser:

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public IActionResult ObtenerFactor(FactorDto dto)
   {
       // ... now you've got the data
   }
   ```

   Now it should works fine.

---

In case you have a complex view model `MyComplexViewModel`, you can combine them in following way:

````
```csharp
public class MyComplexViewModel
{
    public FactorDto FactorDto{get;set;}
    public Abc Abc {get;set;}
    public string A {get;set;}
    // ... feel free to add other properties as you like
}
```
````

And declare the view model as `MyComplexViewModel`:

```
@model MyComplexViewModel
...
<th2>Factores&l;/h2>
...


 <input asp-for="FactorDto.Estatura" name="estatura" type="number" id="estatura" placeholder="168, 190, 155...">
 ...
```